React Trigger Two Different Connections to the Socket Server
Im starting with Sockets
When connect my React app to the socker server trigger two different connection. The app just open one connection and has no other client or device accessing to this
My server are printing every client connect, when i access from any browser only opened one tab, the server register two clients connected
App.js
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null)
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false)
  const [isCreated, setIsCreated] = useState(false)
  const [user, setUser] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = openSocket('http://localhost:3030')
    setSocket(socket)

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      setIsConnected(true)
    })
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      setIsConnected(false)
    })
    socket.on('userCreated', (payload) => {
      setIsCreated(true)
      setUser(payload)
    })
    
  }, [])

  const handlerConection = () => {
    if(isConnected) {
      socket.disconnect()
    } else {
      socket.connect()
    }
  }

Its about the lifecycle of React or is just a case of dev environment who trigger two connections?

What does handlerConnection() think it’s doing exactly?

Just connect and disconnect to the socket. not a functions or feature, just with testing/learning intended
